# Products displayed incorrectly on homepage

Tags: magento2

Clean install of Magento ver. 2.2.1 with the "Ultimo" theme.

I have added 25 products on my homepage using a "CMS product list", but they don't have any hover effect, "Add to wishlist" or "Add to compare" buttons.

This is my homepage: https://havm5.pixact.dk/

The products are displayed correctly in the categories as you can see here: https://havm5.pixact.dk/dametoj/regntoej_dame.html

I inspected the HTMl, the classes are different on the homepage compared to the ones in the categories, the products would be displayed correctly if they had the same classes - is there a way to fix this without editing the Magento files / theme files?

Can this be changed through the admin panel?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

A reason as to why the products are displayed correctly in the category: I used a migration service called "Cart2Cart" which migrated all of the categories, but I have added the products on the homepage myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimo 2 doesn't provide the hover effect on the homepage for some reason.

You can however use the featured slider on your Home CMS page to make it look like the category view.

Details about this can be found in the ultimo guide on chapter 6.1.4:

```
{{block
class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\ProductList\Featured"
template="product/list_featured_slider.phtml"
category_id="3"
block_name="My Products"
}}
```

Above is a code sample to display products from category id 3.

Comment: This doesn't add the hover effect though, also it doesn't format the product text the same way which means that the "Add to cart" button is getting pushed down on a new line. https://havm5.pixact.dk/

Comment: Correct, the hover effect is not available for this feature as I stated in my original answer. Since magento 2 the only place the hover effect is available is on the category pages.

Comment: Oh, I misread that. Would you happen to know about the text formatting? It is an option that can be turned on/off in the admin panel, it makes sure that products stay on the same line regardless of their amount of words in the product title.